# Add safety checks to fastest recompile command in the west

Tags: compile, compile-mode

In my .emacs file, I have my dream recompile function,

```
(require 'compile)
(defun jidanni-recompile ()
  (interactive)(recompile 'nil))
(global-set-key "\C-xc" 'jidanni-recompile)
```

It's "the fastest gun in the west" recompile function.
No ifs, ands, or buts: no questions asked if I want to save
the file (yes) or if I want to use the same command (yes).

OK, if I want to change the command I was using from the compile job I
did two seconds ago, I do M-x compile and enter the new command I want
to start using. Fine.

But the problem comes when I go to some new directory. And I forgot to
do M-x compile to enter the new command, and it switches back to the old
directory and does the old command.

Anyway, I need to make it detect that I have switched directories, and
go back to asking me what command to use in that case. Also in the case
where it's the first compile of the day, and also when I do "C-u C-x c". And in fact it should also notice that I don't seem to be in either the *compilation* buffer, or the buffer I was just in when I did the last recompile, and also ask me if indeed I am sure I still want to use the same compile command as last time.

(New tag idea: recompile .)